# Getting screen height before first display?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView. I populate it with 8 items, that's all that fits vertically on the G1. Some of my users are saying the Droid has a taller screen height, and so I can probably add one or two more items to the ListView to take up the additional space provided.

How could I measure the available height the screen offers at startup, before the UI is displayed? If I see the height can fit more than 8 items, I'd like to add one or two more rows.

Comment: This sounds like a dangerous path you're headed down, because what if the user decides to turn their G1 into landscape mode?  What about smaller screen sizes than the G1, where your current 8 items will be too big?

Comment: Yes excellent point - I'm nervous about doing this to be honest, but wanted to investigate. I'm thinking this could be a reasonable guess: At app startup, get the screen height in portrait mode. Use that as my standard to figure out how many items to display. I'm ok with them starting the app in landscape mode, and having more items that fit in that orientation. Ideally I just want there to be a # of items such that when they are in portrait mode, all items fit without the need for any scrolling,

Thanks

Comment: Is this some sort of dynamically growing list? You could always just take a hammer to the issue and loading 16 items initially. Unless you're doing some crazy stuff for populating each row, I don't imagine it'd be a noticeable difference in speed and that way the list would still look "full" on the higher resolutions without worrying about the hoops to jump through that Daniel mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to the comments made above, but if you really want to go down that road, try this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

You can do that from your main activity, the one that's started from the launcher.

However, this does not take into account the space taken by the notification bar or window decorations, so in reality, you have *less* space than width times height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use the most:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.????????);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;
    Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
  }
}
```